# trouble installing rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to setup a second ruby install in my home directory (a different version of ruby for testing). I've compiled ruby into `~/bin/` and everything is working until I try to install rubygems.

I have `GEM_HOME` set to `~/gems` directory and `GEM_PATH` set to the same. Then I try to install rubygems with

```
~/bin/ruby setup.rb
```

The installation appears to succeed but ruby can't find rubygems after the install.

```
$~/bin/irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
LoadError: no such file to load -- rubygems
    from (irb):1:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

Anyone have any idea why ruby can't find rubygems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to setting `GEM_HOME` you need to run `config` with your path.  Here are the steps from [rubygems.org](http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page83).

```
$ export GEM_HOME=/home/mygemrepository
$ ruby setup.rb config --prefix=/home/mystuff
$ ruby setup.rb setup
$ ruby setup.rb install
```

Answer (score 0):

that fails in exactly the same way. I believe prefix is telling setup.rb where to put rubygems but isn't telling ruby where to find it. Also, the steps from rubygems.org is a different situation. They are installing rubygems in their home folder, but using the systems ruby binary. I'm trying to use a ruby binary from my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it to work. Sometimes a fresh day is all it takes.

The solution
1. i used an older version of gems (1.1.1. to be precise)
2. i didn't use the prefix but i did set GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH